# Android popup keyboard with custom keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, popup

I want to write a custom keyboard for my android app. Some keys has popup keyboard. For the sake of simplicity, I've reduced the number of keys.
My keyboard.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:keyHeight="5%p"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:verticalGap="0pt"
    android:horizontalGap="0pt">

    <Row>
        <Key
            android:codes="12354"
            android:horizontalGap="0%p"
            android:keyLabel="あ"
            android:keyOutputText="あ" /> <!-- a -->

        <Key
            android:codes="12363,12364"
            android:horizontalGap="0%p"
            android:keyLabel="か"
            android:keyOutputText="か"
            android:popupCharacters="かが"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup" /> <!-- ka -->
    </Row>

</Keyboard>
```

My popup.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:keyHeight="5%p"
    android:keyWidth="15%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0pt"
    android:verticalGap="0pt">


</Keyboard>
```

But the results are terrible (keyHeight is 2.5%p in popup):

[image]

And if keyHeight in popup is 5%p:

[image]

How can I fix this popup keyboard? I don't need the margin, I want to see the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not get any answer for four months, I will just suggest a hack. Maybe this will prompt an expert to correct it and give you a real answer:

You could try to replace

```
android:keyHeight="5%p"
```

by an absolute value

```
android:keyHeight="60dip"
```

or maybe try

```
android:keyHeight="60dp"
```

You need to play with the numbers, I have `60dip` for an African language with stacked tone-markers on my own custom keyboard. So replace "60" by different values and see what might work best.

If it works in your virtual devices in your Android Studio, you still need to test on different phones - but maybe you can find a setting for "savely too high" in stead of your present "too low for the characters".